# xcode 4.5 No Errors in my build, but nothing shows in the simulator

Tags: xcode

Very new to xcode. I am working on with a table that when you tap it, will go to a more detailed screen. There are no errors in my build. The simulator loads ok and the app runs but there is nothing in the fields. Any help would be appreciated. I'll edit this soon for the zip file if anyone needs it.

http://www.mediafire.com/?vz98yyfd1c7hf89

Comment: have u connected all UI elements?

Comment: this is pure guesswork at this point ^^

Comment: updated with link to zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to show some code. There are a million examples of this, but most likely candidates are that in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, you are not populating the controls with values from your data. The simplest example of this would be:

1. Have the data be a simple array, e.g. the list of states, and create that array in the init method of the controller and push values into it (or get something that has a list, like UIColor with its list of colors).
2. Then go into cellForRowAtIndexPath and get the value out of the array corresponding to the row. Then have a label there and set the text of the label to that value.
3. You also have to provide an implementation of the delegate methods numberOfSections (1) and numberOfRowsInSection ([array count]).

That should do it.

Comment: i was missing my NSArray arrayWithObjects

thank you the help.

Comment: Can you check my answer? (Glad I was a help!)